# Constant value '-1' cannot be converted to a 'uint', when try `uint mask = ~0;`

Tags: c#

The sample code to demo:

```
public int FindComplement(int num) {
    //uint mask = ~0;       //<-- error CS0031
    //uint mask = (uint)~0; //<-- error

    uint i = 0; 
    uint mask = ~i; //<-- it works

    while((mask&num) != 0) mask <<= 1;

    return (int)~mask^num;
}
```

When I try `uint mask = ~0`, it causes error as follows

> error CS0031: Constant value '-1' cannot be converted to a 'uint'

Then I tried it with code like `uint i = 0; uint mask = ~i`, it works.

My question is why `uint mask = ~0` cause compile error, and is there any other method to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please ask a single question per post - that's how Stack Overflow is designed to work.

Comment: _why `unit mask = ~0` cause compile error_ because `0` is int. Try `~0U` which is uint

Comment: `uint` already exposes a [`MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint32.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) constant (all bits set). Why do you need some other expression to generate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of 0 is `int`. The type of `~0` is still `int`, with a constant value of -1. That's out of range for `uint`, so there isn't any implicit conversion from `~0` to `uint`. (There's only an implicit conversion from a constant of type `int` to `uint` when the constant is in the range of valid values for `uint`.)

The simplest fix is to use a literal of type `uint`:

```
uint mask = ~0U;
```

You *could* cast instead, combined with `unchecked`:

```
uint mask = unchecked((uint)~0);
```

... but that's pretty ugly.

Answer (score 2):

`0` is typed as an `int`, so `~0` is an `int`. For non-negative constants, there is an implicit cast and everything works, but in this case you want:

```
uint mask = ~0U;
```